# how to display image which is in my local server , and it need to be display in the mail content

Tags: php, html, email

i have a image in my local server ,i need to send an activation mail to the user.in that mail content i am trying to use one image using IMG SRC tag.but the image is not displaying in the mail sent to user.kindly give me suggestions

Comment: The image needs to be online. Then you set the online image link in the mail which the user's web browser can access, load and display as well.

Comment: You can display image in base64 format in image tag.

Comment: v can display the image in local server by giving the complete path in the mail content ?

Comment: upload ur image in any of the image hosting sites like http://postimage.org/ and use that image link if you do not have domain and server of your own

Comment: Either you should keep the image online and use the URL or should embed image in the email itself. This link may help you. How to embed images in html email

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-what-why-and-how-of-data-uris-in-web-design--webdesign-8648) is a Tutorial for Data-URIs. There are many information, just read through it!

**TL;DR:**

Encode an image [here](http://www.base64-image.de/)
After encoding you will get a huge link in this format:

```
<img src="data:image/[FORMAT];base64,[BASE64-CODE]" />
```

Example:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,9j4AAQSkZJR/gABA/QEASABIAA … "/>
```

I still would suggest to read through that tutorial. I would want to know, what I am doing on my (local) server …

---

**[EDIT]:**

Best practice - as others already said it - just try to get the picture online. There are many advantages with Base-64-Encoded data, but there are many disadvantages, too!
Just wanted to make sure, that this is not the best solution!

For further information on this topic … [google it](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=4ja_VYeqMsyK8Qf576rIDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=base64%20encoding%20disadvantages)!